# Is there a way to expose a port on my ec2 instance when the process is started after the instance is already initialized?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dynamic, port, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a cloudformation template that launches an ec2 instance as part of an autoscaling group behind an application load balancer. This ec2 instance has a flask app that launches other processes at given ports. For instance, the flask app launches at port 5005, and I have a target group at 5005, so it works fine. However, the flask app launches a separate process at port 8000, and I am having trouble accessing this port as there is no target group for it in the cloudformation template.

Comment: Is something keeping you from creating another target group for that port?

Comment: @kichik The thing is, port 8000 may change; I may want to launch multiple processes that launch at different ports, and increment it so that I have multiple processes running at port 8000, 8001, 8002, etc... I want it to be somewhat dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Either you can edit your CF template and replace port number 5005 to 8000 which will update the target group. Or if you want to keep port 5005, you might need to add another target group with port number 8000.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I should be a bit more specific. The single process on port 8000 may not be the only process I want to launch. My flask app will may launch multiple processes with incrementing port numbers, so I will not be able to add all of them to the template.

Comment: How about an [api call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_RegisterTargets.html) to register targets group whenever you need it.